# Bookmarking and AJAX Post data

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, query-string

So... I'm writing this thing with PHP and JQuery/JS; I am *not* good with either yet....

I want the user to be able to bookmark a page.  Right now, I am sometimes sending a lot of data and sometimes sending a little bit so I learned how to use the jquery ajax/post functions and just pass json.  However, this prevents the user from being able to bookmark a page.  What I am having to do is.... just basically.... actually, I typed it all out, explaining it but no one is going read all that.

So.. I have to reload the data a lot.  I'd like to be able to use the URL query string AND post data with jquery.

so...

- base, base page: `www.domain.com/kims_stuff.php`
- another page: `www.domain.com/kims_stuff.php?type=0&color=grey`

  - but...... i depending on what they click on this page, i might want to send a whole bunch of json with it.... but i'd like the querystring to still show a few things so it can be bookmarked.

Sorry, I'm not explaining this well.  I think I need to just... do... `window.location.href = "?type=0&color=grey"` when I want that query string and from there, I can reload or whatever with the json when I need to pass a lot of data.

Right?  That's what should be done?

But just checking... is there anyway to put one set of data in the url query string and another set of data in the ajax post json?  I am aware that I can load content from other pages into divs on the current page, while keeping the current url... which in this case, the page would already need to have that in the url.

**Or is there a better way of allowing pages to be bookmarked when using jquery and ajax?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you use a URL hash:

```
www.domain.com/kims_stuff.php#type=0&color=grey
```

As your AJAX state changes, you update the hash. When the page loads, it look at the value of the hash, then execute your JS to restore it to the defined state.

Comment: Yeah, I've been playing with that to load certain sections from other pages into divs on the current page.  I didn't realize it could also be used for bookmarking...?  I'm going to try it out and see what's up... I'll either accept your answer when I get back or post some more comments. Thanks.

Comment: Not only that, but it makes Google happy too: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Comment: HMMMMMMMMMM interesting.  Yeah, lol, and I thought you had to put a space between the # and the url.  Cuz that's how the tutorial showed it.  I really don't know what I'm doing but it works so far...